# Regex formula - combine 2 strings retrieved from 1

Tags: regex

I found the problem with typing valid regex forula to retrieve 2 separated strings from 1 string.

Example: I have in original column string `123456789` and I need to take `123` and `789` portion at once.

Do you know how to combine (using one formula) 2 regular expressions like `(?<=^.{0}).{3}` and `(?<=^.{6}).{3}` to have `123` from the 1st expression and `789` from second?

Or you have any idea how to write different regex formula to take 3 characters, miss another 3 and combine with last 3?

I have tried:

```
(?<=^.{0}).{3}|(?<=^.{6}).{3}
(?<=^.{0}(.{3})).*(?<=^.{6}(.{3}))
```

and it didn't work :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: You can use 2 capture groups for example and then combine the 2 groups  `^(\d{3})\d{3}(\d{3})$` https://regex101.com/r/7y26gV/1 But you can not have a single match 123789 or like this `(?<=^)\d{3}(?=\d{6}$)|(?<=^\d{6})\d{3}$` https://regex101.com/r/pv1nnH/1

Comment: Its quite hard to work out what you want to do... do you want to capture those two groups because they are consecutive integers or because they are at the start and end of string? It would be useful to see some examples that should match the regex, and some that shouldn't and the expected outputs

Comment: Basically I need to capture 2 strings from 1 which are separate - it doesn't matter if they are at the beggining or at the end of string. Example: 123_456 - I need 2345 (no _), ABCDEF- i need BDE, (no C) , 1234ABC - i need 23BC  (no 4A) etc

Comment: @Magda You can not get disjoint matches in a single match. The regex can not skip characters in a single match. Are you ok with a capture group or 2 alternatives? What tool or programming language are you using to get those values?

Comment: I cannot use group or 2 captures unfortunately. I use regex to do some basic transformations on columns in reporting tool, but it's out of the box type, no space for flexibility in programming, only single regular expressions :( Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Magda If you can use a replace with regex, then `(?<=^\d{3})\d{3}(?=\d{3}$)` and replace with an empty string. https://regex101.com/r/EVQ78r/1